# c# MVC - Disabling asp.net debugging in config has caused FontAwesome to stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net, font-awesome

I have recently disabled debugging in our config to improve security - see below.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

But have noticed that FontAwesome has stopped working in my browser, and is just showing a small white square.

My browser says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure how to fix this? I've only turned off debugging?

Thanks

Comment: _"disabled debugging in our config to improve security"_ - that's not what that does. Also, it doesn't cause the issue you see. Are you sure the font is deployed and served?

Comment: Its nothing to do with compilation element of config file, make sure the font path is correct and the server is able to serve font files MIME types

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
FYI @CodeCaster I have been researching the debug flag that I mentioned and have learnt that leaving ASP.NET debug mode enabled may result in leaked information about the application or
server in use. In some cases, it may be possible to remotely trigger break-points in the .NET application, which may bring the entire system to a halt.